# "there exists" vs. "there is"

Tags: terminology

Is the difference between "there exists" and "there is" purely stylistic? The book I am using uses "there is" the majority of the time, except for very few cases of "there exists," so I wanted to make sure.

Comment: Yes, it’s purely stylistic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a stylistic choice. Similar to how one may replace "for all" with "for each" or "for any."

Comment: Except that "for any" may be ambiguous.

Comment: I believe this is only the case if you interpret "for any" to mean "for any one," which I fell would be a misinterpretation.

Comment: You also can use ‘whatever’.